# From date of last event, calculate number of days until next regularly scheduled event

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to calculate the number of days since last occurrence.

For example, I have to go to doctors every 90 days. My last doctor visit was on 1/9/14. I need a formula to tell me how many days until my next visit. I need the formula to work as a running formula, so that it updates itself automatically each day. And the criteria is a word (Cairns, Townsville, Melbourne). So each time I go to the doctor I will write which town it was in, in column `B` and the date of visit in column `A`. I want the days remaining before next visit in column `C`. Any ideas?

Comment: How many days until next visit? what? 90 days as you say in the sentence before the previous one.

Comment: If you have two dates simply subtract them.  The difference is the number of days (and the fraction of a day).

Answer (score 1):

The title and objective don't match, but here are both.  If the objective is days remaining, enter the date of the visit as a date (say in A2 for this example).  Days remaining in cell C2:

=a2+90-today()

If your objective is days since last occurence, as in the title, use:

=today()-a2

The today function is always current date.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I want days remaining. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: So update your question...

Comment: @Cameron if this answered your question, be sure to click the green checkmark next to it to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do math on date-formatted cells just as you can on any numeric field.  So if 1/9/14 is in cell A1, then in cell B1 you can simply put =A1+90